# shebang not working for python script

Tags: python, shebang

I've been looking over many answers here on stackoverflow. I've tried absolutely everything. I have this at the top of my AddressConversion.py python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
```

The objective is to run this as a command utility, meaning I could type

```
AddressConversion [options][address]
```

As of now I would settle for being able to type

```
./AddressConversion [options][address]
```

I have done the chmod so the file is executable
I've ran dos2unix on the file to eliminate any random windows characters(which wouldn't seem possible because the file has only been used on Ubuntu.

I've checked the python install with which python with the results

```
/usr/bin/python
```

I've also checked which env and get a similar path
The script will work fine when I use the traditional python command. It also works fine when I type:

```
usr/bin/env python
```

It will open up the python interpreter.
These steps seem to be the solutions suggested anytime someone asks this question. I am getting this error:

```
./AddressConversion.py: line 1: import: command not found
./AddressConversion.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./AddressConversion.py: line 3: `def init_parser():'
```

which seems like it is trying to run it as a shell script or something.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to run the program under Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Did you try using `#!/usr/bin/python` to test?

Comment: If you create a new script with just a shebang line and a print, does that work?

Comment: Sometimes in this question you've written `usr`, sometimes `user`. If it's a typo, please fix it. Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: @khelwood I just ran a test script and it worked wit ./test.py and yes /user/bin/env python opens the python interpreter.

Comment: @SlipFist Sounds like there is some hidden problem with your script, such as it containing some invisible characters.

Comment: @khelwood I ran the dos2unix tool to clean it up.

Comment: @SlipFist Evidently that did not remove the problematic content.

Comment: @AksharPatel I'm using Python 2.7. When I open the interpreter using the usr/bin/evn python it opens and says it's 2.7

Comment: What command do you exactly use to run your script?

Comment: @Guybrush `./AddressConversion.py`

Comment: @SlipFist thanks. Could you upload or paste your script somewhere? I guess we're missing something (e.g. is the shebang exactly on the first line of your script?).

Comment: @Guybrush it is the first line. here's the script https://pastebin.com/26aB5LFt

Comment: @SlipFist: The first line makes use of `python2`. Do `/usr/bin/env python2` properly open Python in your terminal?

Comment: @Guybrush yes that command opens python. I have changed between python, python2 and even eliminating the env part and putting the direct path to python `/usr/bin/python`. I feel like it has to be some character hidden in the code because the shebangs work when I run simple test files. This script just doens't work properly with shebangs

Answer (score 2):

created one file executeme.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("hello")
```

make it as executable (optional)

```
chmod a+x executeme.py
```

reanme the file

```
mv executeme.py executeme
```

Execute now

```
./executeme
```

OUTPUT

```
hello
```

Another option to create one setup.py file, for more you can read [here](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)
in `entry_points` a key name `console_script` in which you can give the name of executor and target module in format 
'name=target'

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='executor',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[,
    ],
    entry_points = {
              'console_scripts': [
                  'executeme=executeme:main',
              ],
          },
)
```

then run the command

```
pip install -e /path/to/setup.py
```

> Installing from local src in Development Mode, i.e. in such a way that
>   the project appears to be installed, but yet is still editable from
>   the src tree.

[pipdoc](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)

Comment: @pipdoc Thanks for your input, I can do that process on any other scripts but not this specific one. That's why I thought it was so weird. By the looks of it I must just have some strange hidden character in my script. There is no other reason for it not to work.

Comment: suggest you to check the indentaions

Comment: I have no idea why, buy copying and pasting it from my pastebin link into a new file called test.py fixed it. Annoying...

Comment: why do we need `./` when calling the file and doesn't work without it even when I am in the same directory?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it ended being because of the CRLF at the end of lines. These were added when the script was created on a windows machine. To check if this is the case use the file command.

```
file script.py
```

It will give you an output like this. "Python script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators"

To remove the CRLF line terminators do the following.

```
dos2unix script.py
```